Clicked event set for multiple block works only once
I have this function to get data from an API, then I create a <div> and set the data into that . After that, for each <div> I created, I set a "click" event for that <div>.
The code worked fine for the first time I clicked a <div>, but after that, the "click" event cannot be triggered anymore, I haven't found the reason, can someone help me?
Thank you, below is the src:
const setSuggestedQuestion = async function () {
    if (!hasSetSuggestedQuestions) {
        /* Get data from the API, response is like this:
                   ["Question 1","Question 2"]   
        */ 
        await getSuggestedMessage()
        hasSetSuggestedQuestions = true
        //Create the div, then set the necessary data for it
        const suggestedDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("mc_suggested_question")[0]
        for (let i = 0; i < suggestedQuestion.data[0].length; i++) {
            const suggestedQuestionDiv = document.createElement('div')
            suggestedQuestionDiv.className = "detail_suggested_question";
            suggestedQuestionDiv.setAttribute("data_suggested_question", suggestedQuestion.data[0][i])
            suggestedQuestionDiv.innerHTML = generateChatElement(link, 9, suggestedQuestion.data[0][i], '');
            suggestedDiv.appendChild(suggestedQuestionDiv);
        }
    
    //Set click event the all of the created div
    const suggestedElements = document.getElementsByClassName("detail_suggested_question");
    for (let suggestedElement of suggestedElements) {
        suggestedElement.addEventListener("click", async function () {
            sendQuestion(this.getAttribute("data_suggested_question"))
        });
    }
}

I get the data, set it into a block, then set a click event for it
I expect the event will be fired anytime I click the block, but it runs only once

Chances are, your listener is actually called on click but then somehing else goes wrong. Did you put a breakpoint at the line of sendQuestion?

@SergeyAKryukov the click itself doesn't trigger, I have put a breakpoint inside both in the click event and the in the sendQuestion function, both doesn't trigger

for a note, I have tried to use event delegation but it doesn't work either

@dragonquila Can you provide executable snippet, IMO, event delegation is best approach for this scenario.

Are you updating then content of a clickable div in the function sendQuestion? Maybe you actually create a new element and the event listener disappears.

If I run the following example, the console.log(this) will return the Window object:


let listitems = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

for (let item of listitems) {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(this); // return Window to the console!
  });
}
<div id="list">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
</div>



Could you try to use the event target instead (e.target), like here:


let listitems = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

for (let item of listitems) {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.target); // return the <div> to the console
  });
}
<div id="list">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
</div>



You are writing in the comments that event delegation doesn't work. In a case like this, where items are created dynamically, I would write code that looks more or less like this (notice that I use closest() to get the right element):


const list = document.getElementById('list');

list.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let item = e.target.closest('.item');
  if (item) {
    console.log(item.dataset.item);
  }
});
<div id="list">
  <div data-item="1" class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div data-item="2" class="item">Item 2</div>
</div>



